# Can a stream create new objects?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I will try to simplify a situation I am facing. There are 2 entities:

```
class Foo {
    String fooProperty;

    @OneToOne
    Bar bar;
}

class Bar {
    String barProperty;
}
```

There is also a DTO class with the attributes from Foo and Bar:

```
class FooDto {
    String fooProperty;
    String barProperty;

    public static FooDto from(Foo foo) {
        return new FooDto(foo.fooProperty, foo.bar.barProperty);
    }
}
```

FooDto is used to deliver huge amounts of data and the conversion can easily be done using streams:

```
fooList.stream().map(FooDto::from).(...)
```

Now, there is a change in requirements and a Foo can have many Bars:

```
@OneToMany
List<Bar> bar;
```

It is also required that it should be generated one FooDto for each containing Bar, like so:

```
Foo(fooProperty="foo1", bar=[Bar(barProperty="bar1"), Bar(barProperty="bar2")])
```

will be converted to:

```
[FooDto(fooProperty="foo1", barProperty="bar1"), FooDto(fooProperty="foo1", barProperty="bar2")]
```

I managed to solve it using a intermediate list but I am still unsure it was the best solution.

I was wondering if it is possible to do something like that using purely streams. I can use maps and filters and generate a result with a equal/smaller size than the 
original input but I can't figure out how to generate a result with more elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation that you are looking for is called `flatMap`.

It operates on a stream of `Foo` objects, takes as argument a function that converts a `Foo` object into a stream of `FooDto` objects and returns a stream combined stream of `FooDto` objects:

```
class FooDto {
    String fooProperty;
    String barProperty;

    public FooDto(String fooProperty, String barProperty) {
        this.fooProperty = fooProperty;
        this.barProperty = barProperty;
    }

    public static Stream<FooDto> from(Foo foo) {
        return foo.bars.stream().map(bar -> new FooDto(foo.fooProperty, bar.barProperty));
    }
}
```

and then:

```
List<FooDto> result = fooList.stream().flatMap(FooDto::from).(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is posible via Streams, you just have to combine `faltMap` with `map`

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Foo {
    String fooProperty;
    List<Bar> bars;

    public Foo(String fooProperty, List<Bar> bars) {
        this.fooProperty = fooProperty;
        this.bars = bars;
    }
}

class Bar {
    String barProperty;

    public Bar(String barProperty) {
        this.barProperty = barProperty;
    }
}

class FooDto {
    String fooProperty;
    String barProperty;

    public FooDto(String fooProperty, String barProperty) {
        this.fooProperty = fooProperty;
        this.barProperty = barProperty;
    }

    public static List<FooDto> from(List<Foo> foos) {
        return foos.stream().
                            flatMap(foo -> foo.bars.stream().
                                    map(bar -> new FooDto(foo.fooProperty, bar.barProperty))).
                            collect(Collectors.toList());
    }


}
```

as an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bar b1 = new Bar("b1");
    Bar b2 = new Bar("b2");
    Bar b3 = new Bar("b3");
    Bar b4 = new Bar("b4");

    Foo foo = new Foo("Foo 1", Arrays.asList(b1,b2));
    Foo foo2 = new Foo("Foo 2", Arrays.asList(b2,b3,b4));
    List<FooDto> result = FooDto.from(Arrays.asList(foo, foo2));
    result.forEach(f -> System.out.println(f.fooProperty + ": " + f.barProperty));
}
```

> Output

```
Foo 1: b1
Foo 1: b2
Foo 2: b2
Foo 2: b3
Foo 2: b4
```

Comment: I used something like that to build the intermediate list. I was really hoping to do something like List<FooDto> dtos = (List<Foo>)fooList.stream.doSomething.collect();

Comment: I think I figured it out... If I return a Stream<FooDto> I can use flatmap and do something like: List<FooDto> dtos = fooList.stream().flatMap(FooDto::from).collect(Collectors.toList());   I will give a try at home.

Comment: @marcellorvalle yes, it is a combination of flatMap and map.